# How can i make android studio default text editor in git in mac os

Tags: git, macos, android-studio

Usually, I use android-studio for development and git via the terminal in mac os. Sometimes when I try to merge branches terminal print this line :
`hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...`
and sublime text opens(which is the current default text editor for me in git), show me a message for the merge command, and want to save and close the editor. how can I set android-studio as the default text editor in git?

I did this for setting sublime as the default text editor in git( ~/.gitconfig) but need a similar command for android-studio:
`editor = /Applications/Sublime\\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl  -n -w`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Cannot change it to your android studio if you are merging in android studio. just remove the sublime and it will be android studio which handle this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Command-line Launcher from the Tools menu in Android Studio.
2. Set `studio --wait` as the Git editor.